# Column doesnot exist error in PostgreSQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have been trying to get the result of a PostgreSQL command. I am getting the following error. I want to get the video id, video name and the created date for that specific video.
[image]

I have all the required columns in the table as shown below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another good example why you shouldn't use mixed case or upper case identifiers. If you never use double quotes (including the CREATE TABLE statements), then you  don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `"tablename.columnname"`, that is *not* interpreted as table name and column name, but as a single identifier. Based on the context in a join condition, PostgreSQL expects it to be a column name.

If you use double quotes, you have to quote column and table separately: `"tablename"."columnname"`